# drawable-land vs drawable

Tags: android, orientation, drawable, landscape

I am not using a layout-land, but do have drawable-land.

The problem is, it uses whichever drawable matches the orientation when the activity **starts**.  I would like it to switch between using the drawable/drawable-land when the phone rotates.  Is there a way to do this easily?  Or should I just copy and paste my layout into layout-land, so that it actually recreates the activity? (I assume that would do the right thing, but ideally I would like it to just refresh the drawable using the correct one when I rotate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can check first device orientation ie manually by

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();

if(width>height)
{
//Landscape
//set your landscape drawable
}
else
{
//portrait
//set your portrait drawable
}
```

so then no need to create "Drawable-land" folder also

Comment: youre right.  i had the configChanges="orientation" in my manifest, which was also the problem.  thanks

Comment: your implementation works.  but i found an easy way to fix what I had already setup, which was just removing a flag that I had set in the manifest.